# How can I parallelize docker run?

Tags: docker

If I run `docker run ...` to start a container, then run a job and shutdown the container, on 16 containers sequentially, it performs at about the same speed as if I launch 16 different processes each running `docker run`. This is on a 16 core machine. How can I fix this?

Our docker images are all developed by different researchers and combined into a transcriptomics pipeline. Each researcher needs to install various configurations which prevents image sharing, though many share a common parent.

I need to test each image. Right now it takes a few minutes to run the full tests, whether I run them sequentially or whether I launch 16 processes and run each in its own process.

Anyone know why this is? Does dockerd only use one core?

Comment: I wonder if you could use Docker Compose here. As far as I know it starts containers in parallel, except where you declare dependencies between two services. Might be worth a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are running docker natively in linux.
Hard to say without more information. I would guess that it is likely that your containers are using more than one thread each, and they are competing for resources.
I would check the resource use by monitoring 'docker stats' as you launch each container to see whats actually happening. Your performance might be limited by other factors, like I/O

Comment: Thanks! The 'docker stats' command is just the tool I needed. That has allowed me to rule out resource contention. Multiple cores are utilized. It looks like some of the docker instances may be grid-locking with each other, probably due to some user code. I am making faster progress now. Thanks!